# Why getting exception when trying to create a folder name based on date time?

Tags: c#, winforms

In the screenshot on the left, what do I get on the textBox Text, and on the right is the exception when clicking on the continue button.

[image: Exception]

The code of the method to create the folder/s :

```
private void CreateDownloadFolders()
        {
            string locationToCreateFolderRadar = textBoxRadarPath.Text;
            string locationToCreateFolderSatellite = textBoxSatellitePath.Text;
            string folderName = "";
            string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd MM.dd.yyyy");
            string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH.mm tt");
            string format = "{0} on {1} At {2}";
            folderName = string.Format(format, date, time);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(locationToCreateFolderRadar + folderName);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(locationToCreateFolderSatellite + folderName);
        }
```

The button click event that calls the CreateDownloadFolders method :

```
private async void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CreateDownloadFolders();

            urls = new List<string>();

            lblStatus.Text = "Downloading...";

            rad.GetRadarImages();
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            foreach (string link in rad.links)
            {
                urls.Add(link);
            }

            await sat.DownloadSatelliteAsync();
            foreach (string link in sat.SatelliteUrls())
            {
                urls.Add(link);
            }

            urlsCounter = urls.Count;

            await DownloadAsync();
        }
```

Maybe because the button click event is type async?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Code and error messages are both text, and should be copied and pasted directly into your post. Information in images can't be found in a search, and images should be used only when the issue cannot be demonstrated any other way, which certainly isn't the case with a text error message.

Comment: what is the value of   string locationToCreateFolderRadar = textBoxRadarPath.Text;
            string locationToCreateFolderSatellite = textBoxSatellitePath.Text;       ?

Comment: @MorenajeRD does it really matter? Clearly OP had a typo in the format string (and was not interested in providing [MCVE] for you) - `string.Format("{0} on {1} At {2}", date, time);` shows 2 parameters for 3 placeholders...

Comment: @MorenajeRD The first one textbox text value is D:\Downloaded Images\Radar and the second textbox text value is D:\Downloaded Images\Satellite both folders exist already and I want to created on each one Radar and Satellite sub folders with the date and time. each time I click the button to create a sub folder in Radar and in Satellite with the date time as the folders names.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov but it's never reaching the string.Format line yet. The error/exception is on the first line in the method.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The line folderName = string.Format(format, date, time); was in original folderName = string.Format(format, textBox1.Text, date, time); I removed the textBox1 because I don't have textBox1 but the error is on the first line.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I see the exception message now it is about the string format index. i tried to put a breakpoint on that line and it's never reach it. strange. it's never continue beyond the first line.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov what should I put then in the string.Format ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your issue is on this line:

```
  folderName = string.Format(format, date, time);
```

you are sending only  two parameters and the format  is  expecting 3:

```
 string format = "{0} on {1} At {2}";
```

you have two ways to solve this:

1:

```
 string format = "{0} on {1} At X"; // expect only 2 parameters
```

or

2:

```
   folderName = string.Format(format, date, time, "something else"); // send all 3 parameters
```

Comment: This line string format = "{0} on {1} At {2}"; and the line in your 1. option solution string format = "{0} on {1} At {2}"; are the same.

Comment: @LibiShalva thanks, i just posted the fix